# UITapGestureRecognizer inside of MPMoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a tapgesturerecognizer inside of an MPMoviePlayer. However when I tap it only shows the "movie menu" (the bar where you can pause etc).
Is there a way to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a MPMoviePlayer or should I just look for other ways to solve my problem?

Have already checked both docs and SO without any success...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I once tried to customize an `MPMoviePlayer`, but it fought back. To succeed with my project I needed to build my own interface around an `AVPlayer` instead.

Since the `MPMoviePlayer` class is a high level class that includes a specific user interface to an `AVPlayer` it's hard to customize. `AVPlayer` can supply a view that displays a movie, but no further user interface. Because it's the lower level class, it will happily work with whatever user interface you design and implement, including interacting with `UITapGestureRecognizer` objects. Since it is the lower level class, you'll need to also implement the rest of the user interface you are happy with in an `MPMoviePlayer`. Adding that interface is not hard. Start with reading the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Comment: Going to bed right now. I'll look into it tomorrow though. Thanks man!